# Java - How to change Mouse-Speed in Windows

Tags: java, mouse, performance

Yeah, thats the Question.

How can I change the Mouse-Speed in Windows in Java?

Greets

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JNI.

See
https://web.archive.org/web/20181204163948/http://www.atwistedweb.com/java/jni.html

Similar question:
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=374029.

C++ code here and mouse speed changing API here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx.

Similar code:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/b866d476-16ac-4313-bc84-6de4cdde806f
-- you need `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.
Since its 23pm here, I will go for it tomorrow and check it out. Seems a little bit complicated, but could be useful in the Future.

Greets

Comment: The Java links are defunct.

Comment: 1st link updated using archive.org link, can't find an archive.org link for the 2nd one